# freebsd pf.conf apply to local

Tags: networking, firewall, freebsd, packet-sniffers, openbsd

i'm working on freebsd 9, and my pf.conf is below

```
#cat /etc/pf.conf
int_if = "em1"
emi = "127.0.0.1"

rdr on $int_if proto tcp from any to any port 12345 -> $emi port 1010

# pfctl -vvvvnf /etc/pf.conf
int_if = "em1"
emi = "127.0.0.1"
@0 rdr on em1 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 12345 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1010 
#
```

and this rules works fine when i tested in other ip -> to local

but i want to apply this rules when local -> local

is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the same rule for the lo0 interface